# How to write to an HTML page using Flask without refreshing the page?

Tags: python, flask

I'm recreating simple web apps to practice. In this website [Password Generator](https://passwordsgenerator.net/), once you press generate password, the generated password will be inputted in the textbox. How do I do this in Flask? The solution I did was redirect to a new webpage containing only the password but I don't think it is a good design.

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
if request.method == "GET":
    return render_template("index.html")
else:
    # Get the input values
    length = int(request.form.get("charnum"))
    numbers = bool(request.form.get("numbers"))
    symbols = bool(request.form.get("symbols"))
    lowercase = bool(request.form.get("lowercase"))
    uppercase = bool(request.form.get("uppercase"))
    similar = bool(request.form.get("excludeSimilar"))
    ambiguous = bool(request.form.get("ambiguous"))

    # Generate Password with the preceding conditions
    password = generate_pass(length, symbols, numbers, uppercase, lowercase, similar, ambiguous)
    return render_template("index.html", password=password)
```

Comment: it needs to use JavaScript - to generate password in JavaScript or to run request (AJAX) to get only generated password from separated function in Flask and put it in textbox.

Comment: I checked this page - it use JavaScript to generate passoword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to use JavaScript to send AJAX request to server. Server can return only password (without HTML) and JavaScript has to put it in textbox.

But page from your link uses JavaScript to generate password directly in browser

---

Minimal working code which uses JavaScript to get values from FORM, send to server, get result from server and put password in FORM.

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string
import random
import string

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.json

        lower_number = int(data.get('lower', 0))
        upper_number = int(data.get('upper', 0))

        password_lower = random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=lower_number)
        password_upper = random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=upper_number)

        password = password_lower + password_upper
        random.shuffle(password)  # change order of chars  (work in-place so doesn't need to assign to variable)

        return "".join(password)

    return render_template_string('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
    Lower: <input type="text" id="lower_id" value="10" /><br/>
    Upper: <input type="text" id="upper_id" value="10" /><br/>
    <button type="submit" name="btn" onclick="generate();return false">GENERATE</button></br>
    <input type="text" id="password_id" /><br/>
</form>
<script>
var password = document.getElementById("password_id");
var lower_input = document.getElementById("lower_id");
var upper_input = document.getElementById("upper_id");

function generate() {
    fetch("/", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            lower: lower_input.value,
            upper: upper_input.value,
        }),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },        
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {password.value = text;})
}
</script>
</body>
</html>''')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.debug = True 
    app.run()
```

---

**EDIT:**

In `fetch` I set

- url `"/"`,
- method `POST`,
- data converted to JSON,
- `content-type` as JSON - so Flask can get it with `request.json`,
- `accept` as JSON - to inform Flask that I expect response as JSON (but I don't respect it and in Flask I send normal text instead of JSON - so I could skip this header)

Because JavaScript uses asynchronous functions so
`fetch` uses `.then()` to execute next function when it gets response from server. This function gets `text`/`body` from response. It also has to wait for result and it uses `.then()` to execute next function when it finally get text from response. And this function puts this text in `<input>` for password.

Mozilla: [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch)

Comment: Can you explain what you did with fetch's body? And also can you point me to a resource to learn more about this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Mozilla: [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch)

Comment: I added some description to answer.

Answer (score 1):

for real-time response in webpages, you must use javascript. you can either call your *flask* API with javascript (using tools like *AJAX*,...), then put the generated password in the textbox or implement your password generation algorithm in javascript.